# Generalization of cumulative probability models for ordinal Y

Tags: regression, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

There are many models in existence for ordinal $Y$, for example the proportional odds ordinal logistic model, the continuation ratio model, and the cumulative probit model.  The first and third of these are in a class of models specifying Prob$(Y \leq j | X) = F(\alpha_{j} + X\beta)$ where $F$ is a non-decreasing function (e.g., logistic or normal CDF).  This can be generalized by having a family of functions (e.g., a 3-parameter family) and estimating the parameters of this family in addition to $\alpha, \beta$.  Or perhaps there is a way to do this non-parametrically in $F$.  Has anyone seen any methods developed along these lines?  Among other things, this would be a competitor of quantile regression.

Comment: My basic understanding of these ordinal regression methods is that they extensions of the GLM (usually a link function is applied to the LHS). $F$ is a cumulative link. The advantage of explicitly stating $F$ is that the parameters are interpretable. But if $F$ is allowed to be anything, then perhaps the objective is more for prediction than inference. Is that correct? How could one articulate the constraints relative to a general additive multinomial model?

Comment: I think that's mainly correct.  You could still do inference though if you are willing to talk about effect ratios that are not quite as specific as odds or hazard ratios.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is [this manuscript](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5675816/) the follow-up of your line of thinking from this question?

Comment: I'm one of the authors of that paper.   That is using a traditional simple $F$.